# Java code to use Ical rrule and generate next recurrence date

Tags: icalendar, rrule

I need a java code snippet to parse ICal rrule and generate the next recurrence date.

There is a Java library specifically for parsing RRULEs called google-rfc-2445.

The following link contains an example using the library where you supply a start date along with an RRULE and it prints out the dates.

http://google-rfc-2445.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

But I don't want to use the google lib.

Comment: here a good answer with beeweekly library: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319008/how-to-parse-ical-rrule-in-java/56740923#56740923

Answer (score 1):

You can use ical4j: https://github.com/ical4j/ical4j

More specifically, you can use the Component.calculateRecurrenceSet() method